# Why does ROWS[0] return entire table to DataRow?

Tags: c#, datatable

When I look at row count for dr near end of code - it says it is a table and has same number of rows as dt!

Why?

```
static public bool GetLastMTM(out DataRow dr)
{
    dr = null;

    try
    {
        string commandText = "SELECT [TIMESTAMP] FROM [" + DBName + "].[dbo].[tblMTM] ORDER BY [TIMESTAMP] DESC";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
        {
            Connection = conn,
            CommandText = commandText
        };

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);


        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        ds.Reset();

        da.Fill(ds);

        dt = ds.Tables[0];

        if (dt.Rows.Count < 1)
            return false;

        dr = dt.Rows[0];

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception er)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

> - dr  {System.Data.DataRow}   System.Data.DataRow         HasErrors   false   bool
> - ItemArray   {object[1]} object[]        RowError    ""  string      RowState    Unchanged   System.Data.DataRowState
> - Table   {Table} System.Data.DataTable
> - base    {Table} System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent {System.Data.DataTable}       CaseSensitive   false   bool
> - ChildRelations  {System.Data.DataRelationCollection.DataTableRelationCollection}    System.Data.DataRelationCollection
>     {System.Data.DataRelationCollection.DataTableRelationCollection}
> - Columns {System.Data.DataColumnCollection}  System.Data.DataColumnCollection
> - Constraints {System.Data.ConstraintCollection}  System.Data.ConstraintCollection
> - DataSet {System.Data.DataSet}   System.Data.DataSet
> - DefaultView {System.Data.DataView}  System.Data.DataView        DisplayExpression   ""  string
> - ExtendedProperties  Count = 0   System.Data.PropertyCollection      HasErrors   false   bool        IsInitialized   true    bool
> - Locale  {en-GB} System.Globalization.CultureInfo        MinimumCapacity 50  int         Namespace   ""  string
> - ParentRelations {System.Data.DataRelationCollection.DataTableRelationCollection}    System.Data.DataRelationCollection
>     {System.Data.DataRelationCollection.DataTableRelationCollection}
>       Prefix  ""  string
>       PrimaryKey  {System.Data.DataColumn[0]} System.Data.DataColumn[]
>       RemotingFormat  Xml System.Data.SerializationFormat
> - Rows    {System.Data.DataRowCollection} System.Data.DataRowCollection
> - base    {System.Data.DataRowCollection} System.Data.InternalDataCollectionBase
>     {System.Data.DataRowCollection}       Count   699 int

Comment: _"When I look at row count"_ how are you doing so?  Are you hovering the mouse over it in the debugger?  Or using watch window?  Is the mouse over the right variable?  Have you made a typo? (`dr` and `dt` are only one key apart etc).

Comment: Stop writing 2-letter variable names. Every single editor out there has code completion, the only thing that you're achieving by using 2-letter variables is to annoy anyone trying to read your code. This is an insult to programming as a workmanship. Use descriptive variable names. Always.

Comment: Yes - I hover. BUT here is output from Watch in yellow (see question). dr appears to be a table with 699 rows...

Comment: Uh, are you looking at the [`.Table` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.table(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `DataRow`?

Comment: RowCount on a DataRow? wat

Comment: The 699 count is associated to a DataRowCollection not to the dr variable

Comment: That maybe - but my DataRow dr contains 699 rows! I can any access them!

Comment: Your `DataRow` doesn't contain any rows (rather it represents exactly _one_ row).  It contains a link back to the table it came from, and that table contains the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch window has the feature to traverse through private references and parent objects which are normally hidden and not accessible from code. In your case you are seeing the `DataRow.Table` property which is just a reference to the parent object. If you dig in to `Table.Row[0]` you can again see the table property and you can see the table again. You can do this in your free time and keep going deeper and deeper just for fun. I have wasted days of my life trying to reach end of the tree.